# Selecting suboptimal features in scikit learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

In scikit learn, I can select the `k` best features by using `sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest` with some feature selection algorithm.  Is it possible to select the worst features, or the median features, or anything other than the best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have *n* features, then selecting the worst *k* features can be found by asking what are the best *n - k* features (which you describe how to do in your question), and then just taking the complement.

Otherwise, you can use [`sklearn.feature_selection.RFE`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html) which returns a *ranking* of the features. With a ranking, clearly you can find the best, worst, median, and so forth.